# Hibernate Exception entity class not found

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an application which uses Hibernate for database transactions, I have mapped all the tables in my database and when I tried to get data from a one table I get following error, please help,

```
Jan 18, 2012 1:19:57 PM org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl <init>
INFO: building session factory
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found: mappings.Log
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.ofm.mnu.persistence.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:25)
    at org.ofm.mnu.persistence.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:14)
    at org.ofm.mnu.CRUD.GrnMainCrud.retrive(GrnMainCrud.java:15)
    at org.ofm.mnu.views.functions.GRN.fillGrnTable(GRN.java:224)
    at org.ofm.mnu.views.functions.GRN.<init>(GRN.java:36)
    at org.ofm.mnu.views.home.main.MainFrame.btnSample_2ActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:233)
    at org.ofm.mnu.views.home.main.MainFrame.access$500(MainFrame.java:31)
    at org.ofm.mnu.views.home.main.MainFrame$6.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:185)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found: mappings.Log
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.getGetter(PropertyFactory.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierProperty(PropertyFactory.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
    at org.ofm.mnu.persistence.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:20)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mappings.Log
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:96)
    ... 52 more
```

this is my configuration file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123789</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/ofm_mnu_jvs</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/StOls2.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ZcIcsYear.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ZcFarmerCompany.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ZcFarmerCrop.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/Ledger.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/SysUpdate.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/IcmtSub.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/VwJcsummary.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/StRds.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/StOls5.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/Company.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/SrnSub.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/Supplier.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/CostCenters.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/StSpg.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/JcInOutCrop.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/EEmail.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/IcmtMain.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ImtMain.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ZcUser.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/Temp.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/Factory.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/VwAllStokMove.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/OldStock.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/StFgs.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/StOls1.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/CostVariable.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/JcMain.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/EdnSub.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/Commission.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ItemCode.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/StOls4.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/MonthEndBalance.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/GrnSub.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/RunningNo.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/VwAllStock.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ZcTemfarCrop.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ZcBlock.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/VwAllStokMove1.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/San.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/Log.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/VwLedger.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ItemGrade.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/Stocktype.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ZcFarmerCer.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ZcCetification.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/VwExcropBalance.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ZcFarmerAccount.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ActMonths.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/Batchno.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/Certification.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/Uom.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/AUser.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/DesNote.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/StOls3.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ZcSociety.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ItemLedger.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ZcFarmerReg.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/StBfg.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ImtSub.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/Mtn.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/StRaw.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/GrnMain.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/Ccn.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/VwTotOutQty.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/EdnMain.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/SrnMain.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ItemCost.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/StOgs.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/ZcTemfarMain.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: please make sure the class mappings.Log does exist.@Harsha

Comment: The mappings.Log class doesn't exist, or is not in the classpath.

Comment: I am not using a class called "mappings.Log" I've generated daos and mapping files using Netbeans 7.1, could it be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably is because there is something missing in the mapping.
Check whether all Pojos are mapped with qualified class names to the tables.
If you can provide the configuration file that can help.

Comment: you do have this in the mappigs section
    <mapping resource="org/ofm/mnu/mappings/Log.hbm.xml"/>

Comment: can you paste this file? it is possible there are some issues in this.